# Union of three subspaces is equal to the vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A real vector space $V$ is the union of three subspaces $P$, $Q$, $R$ of $V$. Prove that, one of $P$, $Q$, $R$ is $V$.

I've tried different methods to solve it, but everytime, I had to assume that P U Q is a subspace, which is not necessary here.

Comment: Have you seen/done the same exercise with two subspaces?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose that you already know that the similar statement with $2$ subspaces holds. Then you can assume that none of the three spaces is contained in another one.

Take $v\in V\setminus P$ and $w\in P\setminus(Q\cup R)$. Consider the line $l=\{v+\lambda w\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $l\cap P=\emptyset$ and $l\cap(Q\cup R)$ has one point, at most. But $l$ is a line! Therefore $l\neq P\cup Q\cup R$.